# Codemagic dont unloaded a flutter app assembly in Appstore Connect

Tags: ios, flutter, testflight, codemagic

I'm trying to build my project using codemagic and put it on testflight (version in pubspec.yaml: 1.1.0), but for some reason, it is possible to put it in the appstore (screenshot number 1), but not on testflight (screenshot 2)

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noRSi.png)

[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaHl2.png) - no assemblies

My settings follow the instructions, but nothing comes out anyway.

[iOS code signing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tz0wZ.png)

[App Store Connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYsaN.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oscf.png)

What is the problem?

Comment: You should contact Codemagic. They have a Slack support as you'll not get it here for being an off topic question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the mistake was.  The mistake was that I had a standard flutter icon.  I changed the icon to another one without transparency and enlarged the version.  After that, the application went to appstore connect